# Android: Gallary like Swipe effect

Tags: android, gallery, swipe

I've list of image locations (sdcard image path) in an ArrayList. Is it possible for me to pass it to Gallary and let user to swipe through the images??

if not, how can I implement something similar to that??

Some help appreciated. Thanks for your time in advance.

PS: I searched online but couldn't find exactly what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can directly use `Gallery` class. here are some code snippets but there are loads of examples available online for this.

`onCreate(Bundle b)` should look like this.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGallery.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is `main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

`res/values/attrs.xml`  shold look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="HelloGallery">
        <attr name="android:galleryItemBackground" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

`Adapter` class should be as follows

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;

    private Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2,
            R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4,
            R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6,
            R.drawable.sample_7
    };

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        TypedArray attr = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = attr.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        attr.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mImageIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

        return imageView;
    }
```

This example is available [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html). have a look at it.

Comment: But this doesn't have swipe effect na?? we need to click the thumbnail. I need to have swipe effect just like we have it in the default Android Gallary.

Comment: it has similar swipe effect. otherwise look at coverflow. which extends gallery.

Comment: swipe effect will be available to the thumnails rite?? but I want the swipe effect to the images. I don't even want thumbnails. Just show images full screen with fling effect. cover flow looks nice though. Trying out few examples

Comment: ohh buddy instead of putting imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
 keep them fillparent and warpcontent inplace of 150, 100 you get full images not thumbnails with this swipe effect

Comment: I didn't think like dat. I"m gonna try :) thanks. I'll accept your answer once I finish it. Thanks alot for your time :)

Comment: it worked. Now I need to figure out how to pass sd card URI instead of the images in the drawables. Thanks :)